# D3.js update graph when pushing new nodes

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to add new nodes to a D3 graph dynamically by nodes.push({"id": item, "group": 1, "size": 30}); but when I do this there is a visual bug where there are duplicates. Anytime I update() I get a double of whatever was already there. Anyone have any advice? Would be appreciated.

```
    var node;
    var link;
    var circles
    var lables;

    function update(){
        node = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("g")

        link = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "links")
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

        circles = node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", function(d) { return (d.size / 10) + 1})
            .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(3); })
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended))
                .on("click", clicked);

        lables = node.append("text")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.id;
            })
            .attr('x', 6)
            .attr('y', 3)
            .style("font-size", "20px");

        node.append("title")
            .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

        simulation
            .nodes(nodes)
            .on("tick", ticked);

        simulation.force("link")
            .links(links);
    }

    function ticked() {
        link
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking just at the nodes (the links are essentially the same issue), every time you update your data you:

1. Create a new parent `g` (`svg.append("g")`)
2. Select all the child `g` elements of that new parent `g` (`.selectAll("g")`). Since this new parent `g` has no children - you just made it, nothing is selected.
3. Bind data to the selection (`.data(nodes)`)
4. Using the enter selection, append a `g` for each item in the data array (as there are no elements in the selection, everything is entered (the enter selection creates an element in the DOM for every item in the data array for which no corresponding element exists in the selection.)
5. Append a circle to each newly appended `g`. (`.enter().append("g")`)

Nowhere do you select the already existing nodes - these are just cast aside. They are ignored by the tick function because `link` and `node` refer to selections of newly created nodes and links. Neither do you remove the old links and nodes - so they just sit there for all eternity or until you close the browser.

The canonical solution is to:

- Append structural elements once. I say structural in reference to the parent `g` elements: they aren't data dependent, they're organizational. They should be appended once outside of the update function.
- Use the update function to manage (create, update, remove) elements that are dependent on the data: the nodes and links themselves. Anything that depends on the data needs to be modified in the update function, nothing else.

So we could append the parent g elements outside of the update function:

```
var nodeG = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodes");
var linkG = svg.append("g").attr("class", "links");
```

Then in the update function we can use those selections to conduct the enter/update/exit cycle. This is slightly complicated in your case, and many others, because we have nodes represented by a `g` with child elements. Something like the following:

```
function update() {

    var node = nodeG.selectAll("g")
       .data(nodes)

    // remove excess nodes.
    node.exit().remove();

    // enter new nodes as required:
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr(...

    // append  circles to new nodes:
    nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr(...

    // merge update and enter.
    node = nodeEnter.merge(node);

   // do enter/update/exit with lines.
    var link = linkG.selectAll("line")
       .attr(...

   link.exit().remove();

    var linkEnter = link.enter().append("line")
      .attr(...

    link = linkEnter.merge(link);

   ...
```

Which in your case may look like:

```js
// Random data:
let graph = { nodes: [], links : [] }

function randomizeData(graph) {
  // generate nodes:
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 6;

  let newNodes = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++)  {
    if (graph.nodes[i]) newNodes.push(graph.nodes[i]);
    else newNodes.push({ id: i, 
                        color: Math.floor(Math.random()*10), 
                        size: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 2),
                        x: (Math.random() * width), 
                        y: (Math.random() * height)
                      })
  }
  // generate links
  let newLinks = [];
  let m = Math.floor(Math.random() * n) + 1;
  for(let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    a = 0; b = 0;
    while (a == b) {
     a = Math.floor(Math.random() * n); 
     b = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
    }
    newLinks.push({source: a, target: b})
    if(i < newNodes.length - 2) newLinks.push({source: i, target: i+1})
  }
  return { nodes: newNodes, links: newLinks }
}
// On with main code:

// Set up the structure:
const svg = d3.select("svg"),
   width = +svg.attr("width"),
   height = +svg.attr("height");
   
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
         
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).strength(0.004))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  // to attract nodes to center, use forceX and forceY:
  .force("x", d3.forceX().x(width/2).strength(0.01))
  .force("y", d3.forceY().y(height/2).strength(0.01));
  
const nodeG = svg.append("g").attr("class","nodes")
const linkG = svg.append("g").attr("class", "links")

graph = randomizeData(graph);
update();

// Two variables to hold our links and nodes - declared outside the update function so that the tick function can access them.
var links; 
var nodes;

// Update based on data:
function update() {

   // Select all nodes and bind data:
   nodes = nodeG.selectAll("g")
      .data(graph.nodes);
      
   // Remove excess nodes:
   nodes.exit()
      .transition()
      .attr("opacity",0)
      .remove();
   
   // Enter new nodes:
   var newnodes = nodes.enter().append("g")
       .attr("opacity", 0)
       .call(d3.drag()
       .on("start", dragstarted)
       .on("drag", dragged)
       .on("end", dragended))
      
   // for effect:
   newnodes.transition()
       .attr("opacity",1)
       .attr("class", "nodes")

   newnodes.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return (d.size * 2) + 1})
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.color); })

   newnodes.append("text")
      .text(function(d) {  return d.id; })
      .attr('x', 6)
      .attr('y', 3)
      .style("font-size", "20px");
      
   newnodes.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
   
   // Combine new nodes with old nodes:
   nodes = newnodes.merge(nodes);
   
   // Repeat but with links:
   links = linkG.selectAll("line")
       .data(graph.links)
       
   // Remove excess links:
   links.exit()
      .transition()
      .attr("opacity",0)
      .remove();
   
   // Add new links:
   var newlinks = links.enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
      
   // for effect:
   newlinks 
       .attr("opacity", 0)
       .transition()
       .attr("opacity",1)      

   // Combine new links with old:
   links = newlinks.merge(links);
         
         
   // Update the simualtion:
   simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes) // the data array, not the selection of nodes.
      .on("tick", ticked)
      .force("link").links(graph.links)
      
   simulation.alpha(1).restart();
      
            
}
   
function ticked() {
   links // the selection of all links:
     .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
     .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
     .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
     .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
         
   nodes
     .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
     })
}         
     
     
     function dragstarted(d) {
                if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                d.fx = d.x;
                d.fy = d.y;
            }
         
            function dragged(d) {
                d.fx = d3.event.x;
                d.fy = d3.event.y;
            }
         
            function dragended(d) {
                if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
            }
         
d3.select("button")
  .on("click", function() {
    graph = randomizeData(graph);
    update();
  
  })
```

```css
        
                .links line {
                    stroke: #999;
                    stroke-opacity: 0.6;
                }
         
                .nodes circle {
                    stroke: #fff;
                    stroke-width: 1.5px;
                }
```

```html
<button> Update</button>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

*Note*

I've updated the force paramaters a bit to use forceX and forceY: forces which attract the nodes to the center. The centering force only ensures the center of gravity is a specific value, not how close the nodes must be.

Alternative approaches:

Of course, you could just remove everything and append it each time: but this limits ability to transition from one dataset to the next and is generally not canonical.

If you only need to enter elements once (no elements need to be added or removed during updates) then you could avoid using the full enter/update/exit cycle and append once outside the update function, updating node/link attributes with new data on update rather than using the more involved enter/update/exit cycle in the snippet above.

Comment: Sorry, I am really out of my comfort zone with this front end stuff. Cannot read property 'selectAll' of undefined when selecting .selectAll("g"). Did you mean to selectAll from svg? Here is where I am at so far https://pastebin.pl/view/cac5c658

Your help is really appreciated! This is my final project :/

Comment: I'm not seeing where that particular error would come from - I do see a few issues in the pastebin though: exit should be exit() on line 9. On line 44 and 50 `node` and `link` are the parent `g` elements here, not the links and nodes themselves (`links` and `nodes`, but these selections are not scoped here - so these could be the data array for nodes and links instead of the selection of elements for links and nodes). Then it also looks like you are using the selection `nodes` as the data array for `simulation.nodes()` so we might have lost a reference to the original data array.

Comment: I'm a bit preoccupied, but will come back to this later tonight with a working example and update the answer.

Comment: Originally I was loading from json, then manually populate the nodes and link array to create the graph. Thanks for the time. You can reference everything I have here https://pastebin.pl/view/0ace449e (deletes after 24 hours) so you can see what I am trying to accomplish. When you type in the box nodes and edges are added to the graph. 

I work tonight but am looking forward to seeing your advice later tonight or tomorrow morning. Thanks again! It means a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I can't put in words how much your help means. I do have one final question. The update() method does a great job of adding new links and nodes but what if I wanted to change a current node? For example 

    function clicked(event, d) {
        if (event.defaultPrevented) return; // dragged
        graph.nodes[d].size += 10;
        console.log(graph.nodes[d].size)

???
updating does not change the size

Comment: You can set all updated *and* entered nodes size at the same time after merging the two selections here: `nodes = newnodes.merge(nodes)` using `nodes.attr(...`. If you just want to set the updated nodes size, use `nodes` before the merge.