# d3.js - join data update behavior wired

Tags: d3.js

This demo try to update data when click the graph. it use the join method but looks like data and axis have been overlapped after click. the previous drawing not been cleared!

```js
console.clear()
click_to_update()
function click_to_update() {
  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width',600)
    .attr('height',400)
    .style('border','5px solid red')
  var frame = svg.append('g').attr('class','frame')
  frame.append('g').attr('class','xaxis')
  frame.append('g').attr('class','yaxis')
  
  d3.select('svg').on('click', function(){
    var data = fetch_data()
    refresh_graph(data)
  })

  var data = fetch_data()
  refresh_graph(data)

  function refresh_graph(data){
    var svg = d3.select('svg')
    var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeSet3)
    var margin = {left: 40,top: 10, right:10,bottom: 60},
        width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var g = d3.select('.frame')
  .attr('transform',`translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)

    var xrange = data.map(function(d,i) { return i; })
    var x = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain(xrange)
    .range([0, width]);

    var ymax = d3.max(data,d => d.value)
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,ymax])
    .range([height, 0]);

    var drawpath = function(d,i) {
      var ax = x(i)
      var ay = y(d.value)
      var bx = x(i)
      var by = y(0)
      var path = ['M',ax,ay,'L',bx,by]
      return path.join(' ')
    }

    var g1 = g.selectAll('path')
    .data(data)
    .join('path')
      .attr('stroke','gray')
    .attr('stroke-width',1)
      .style('fill', (d, i) => colors(i))
      .transition()
      .attr('d', drawpath)

    g.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
        .join('circle')
      .attr('fill','red')
      .attr('cx',(d,i) => x(i))
      .attr('cy',(d,i) => y(d.value))
      .attr('r',5)

    var xaxis = d3.select('.xaxis')
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    var yaxis = d3.select('.yaxis')
    .attr('transform','translate(-5,0)')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  }

  function fetch_data(){
    var num = parseInt(Math.random()*20) + 5
    var data = d3.range(num).map(d => {
      return {value:Math.random()}
    })
    return data
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Everytime you update you add a new `g` with no child elements and you then join using that new `g` which results in everything being entered every time. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68290277/7106086) for an explanation

Comment: Also, you are appending a new `g` for the axes each time - append those outside the refresh function and then call the axes on them inside it.

Comment: @AndrewReid Awesome, updated with the suggestion but the axis update will lost the line, numbers updated correctly!  Please help check what's wrong!

Comment: Will take a look in a bit.